# What would be an example of an attack that exploits escape characters?

Tags: sql-injection, html

As far as I know escape characters are characters which change the meaning of the following character. In HTML for example the `&` is an escape character that declares the beginning of an entity reference. What is an entity?  Well... isn't this a combination of characters used to represent special characters. In HTML for example `&ln` is used to represent `<`.

Now, as I am new to the subject of computer security, can anybody help me in finding an attack that exploits these escape characters? 
I realize I have mentioned HMTL a lot. So there must be an exploit of HTML code that targets escape sequences. And I have heard the same is true for SQL. I don't know any particular escape sequences for SQL - is SQL injection considered an attack that makes use of escape characters? I mean SQL injection often targets the single quote.

Comment: So I am just thinking: Should an attacker place some malicious code in the URI section of a URL, they need to use escapse-sequences such as `%3B` for semicolon since the semicolon is a reserved character for the URI section... anyways, I am still really confused

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider this query:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password';
```

Assume single qoutes are escaped, but the escape character `\` is not. Then, use `user\` as username and an SQL expression (`OR 1=1 --`) as password:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='user\' AND password=' OR 1=1 -- ';
```

Now, the database searches for a user with the username `user' AND password=`, or where one equals one. The quote starting the password value is now interpreted as closing the username value.

Comment: thank you so much Sjoerd, now I get it!!!

Comment: Hey, I just noticed two points: You wrote: "Now, the database searches for a user with the username `user' AND password=` but I think you meant to say `user AND password=` ... second point: Shouldn't we escape the single quote that ends the password-value as well? I mean, is this expression: `OR 1=1 -- '; ` correct? There is no single quote starting this expression. And can you tell me what the dashes `--` are for?